# Why can I not call toArray() on FirebaseListObservable?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

In an Ionic Project, I have:

`import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';`

and a class with the field:

`songs: FirebaseListObservable<any>;`

therefore, the line of code:

`this.songs = db.list('/songs');`

works and allows me to put the line:

`<button ion-button ouline *ngFor="let song of songs | async">`

in my html without problem.

Now, `FirebaseListObservable` extends the RxJS `Observable` ([source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/firebase_list_observable.ts)).
Furthermore, `Observable` has a method [`toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray). But, when I run my project, I see:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'.
```

Why is this? Is there another way I can get an array from what `songs` is observing?

Comment: AngularFire2 does not import RxJS in its entirety and does not use imports that patch the `Observable` prototype. You'll need to import the `toArray` prototype patch yourself. See the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html).

Comment: I added the line `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray;'` to my code, but then saw this error: `Type "Observable<any[]>" is not assignable to type "any[]". Property "length" is missing in type "Observable<any[]>".`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really sure why the `toArray()` not working , but i can suggest you a way to get the array you want from the DB.( I usually do that when i want just the array without the ability to listen to any changes of the DB - like Observable does)  :

```
this.db.list('/songs')
.first().toPromise()
.then(response => {
  //code to handle the response - in this case its a list

  This.items = response;
})
.catch(error => { //error code here });
```

dont forget to import the `rxjs` first and toPromise

I really hope it fits your wish and helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what I should put in `//code to handle the response - in this case its a list`?

Comment: Oh, I understand - I can leave that part empty if I want and `this.items` will still be the list that I want.

Comment: if I do `console.log(response)` inside of that anonymous function, then it shows the array that I want, but `this.items` is not the what I want. So I tried putting `var data;` above that code, and then assigning `data = response;` inside the function, but this does not work either. How can I assign `respond` to another variable?

Comment: You can try to assign the response to `this.items` . I will edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: OK, thanks so much. That works, but because it does not change `this.items` to `response` immediately, if I try to do something with `this.items`, I do not know whether or not it will have the old value or the new one. How can I guarantee that `this.items` is updated by the time I work on it? Or is that too complex of a question for the comments section and without full context?